# Concatenate top row cells if column below has 1

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

I'm looking at a large database of 1s and 0s with named columns, like this:

```
red    blue   green  orange purple
────── ────── ────── ────── ──────
0      0      1      0      1 
0      1      0      0      0
```

I want to concatenate all the headings (by row) where the row has a "1" below that heading. So ideally the first one would equal "green, purple" and the second would just read "blue". I have a large amount of data so anything with nesting of a hundred "IF" functions doesn't make sense.

I've tried

> =IF(B1:B5=1, CONCATENATE(A1:A5), "")

and a couple things close to that, but I'm not finding an obvious way to get it. I also don't really have time or enough knowledge to deal with VBA. I appreciate all help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

String concatenation over more than a few cells is best left to a VBA *User Defined Function* (aka *UDF*) even without setting criteria. Your situation of *"nesting of a hundred "IF" functions"* would certainly put it in this category.

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immedaitely use the pull-down menus to Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the following into the new pane titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*.

```
Public Function conditional_concat(rSTRs As Range, rCRITs As Range, Optional sDELIM As String = ", ")
    Dim c As Long, sTMP As String
    For c = 1 To Application.Min(rSTRs.Cells.Count, rCRITs.Cells.Count)
        If CBool(rCRITs(c).Value2) Then _
            sTMP = sTMP & rSTRs(c).Value & sDELIM
    Next c
    conditional_concat = Left(sTMP, Application.Max(Len(sTMP) - Len(sDELIM), 0))
End Function
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Use this UDF like any native Excel worksheet function. The syntax is,

```
conditional_concat(<range of strings>, <range of conditions>, [optional] <delimiter as string>)
```

[image: Conditional String Concatenation]

The formula in G2 is,

```
=conditional_concat(A$1:E$1, A2:E2)
```

Fill down as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be to add five extra columns and explicitly enter 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple' where the corresponding column is a 1
so you could do:

Red column 'r':
`=IF(col_red=1,"red,","")`

Blue column 'b':
`=IF(col_blue=1,"blue,","")`

Green column 'g':
`=IF(col_green=1,"green,","")`

orange column 'o':
`=IF(col_orange=1,"orange,","")`

Purple column 'p':
`=IF(col_purple=1,"purple,","")`

and in another column concatenate these columns (change the references to the respective columns etc) `=LEFT(F2 & G2 & H2 & I2 & J2,LEN(F2 & G2 & H2 & I2 & J2)-1)` (I found the concatenate function errored because of the erroneous rows

Gives this result:
[image: Result of the functions listed above in answer]

I have experimented a little with array functions with no success which may be a way to solve this.