# Excel - Retrieve list of column names with cells containing >0 in one row

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

I have a huge spreadsheet of bird species sighting data, each column name is the name of a species and each row in column A is a number associated with a geographical location where the species count was taken. so each cell under each species is a count of how many times it was seen at its respective location.

What I want is a function that will give me a list of column names that had values `>0` at that location. Everything I've found has shown me how to find the first value `>0` but I want a list that could contain like 50 species names.

The idea at the end is that for each geographical point I just have a list of species that have been seen there. I'm assuming the function would start with INDEX from what I've read but not sure how to proceed.

If VBA is the only way forward, that's fine but I am very new to it so suggestions on what would accomplish this would be welcome.

[image: example of data]

Comment: You should be able to adapt the answer to [Concatenate top row cells if column below has 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679758/concatenate-top-row-cells-if-column-below-has-1/28680713#28680713).

Comment: FWIW, if you have the latest Office 365 then the following array formula will do it for the example data. `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:D2>0,$B$1:$D$1,""))` being and array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jeeped gave in the comment above, here is the answer adapted to your situation, from his post of the linked answer.

Since you are handling 50 columns, the handling is creating a VBA User Defined Function.

This is how you create one:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
2. When the VBE opens, in the menus select Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>).
3. Paste the following into the window.

---

```
Public Function conditional_concat(rSTRs As Range, rCRITs As Range, Optional sDELIM As String = ", ")
    Dim c As Long, sTMP As String
    For c = 1 To Application.Min(rSTRs.Cells.Count, rCRITs.Cells.Count)
        If CBool(rCRITs(c).Value2) Then _
            sTMP = sTMP & rSTRs(c).Value & sDELIM
    Next c
    conditional_concat = Left(sTMP, Application.Max(Len(sTMP) - Len(sDELIM), 0))
End Function
```

4. Save the workbook.

Now you can use this function in the formula for the cells on your worksheet.

In your case, add the following into the second row in the "species found" column (**BB** is being your last column of species):

```
=conditional_concat(A$1:BB$1, A2:BB2)
```

Then you can copy-paste this on the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Headerr(rIN As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Headerr = ""
    For Each r In rIN
        If r.Value > 0 Then Headerr = Headerr & "," & r.EntireColumn.Cells(1).Value
    Next r
    If Headerr <> "" Then Headerr = Mid(Headerr, 2)
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

This example uses only five columns, but that is not a limit.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**